# What is the difference between Search Bar vs. Search Bar & Search Display Controller?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, uisearchbar

What is the difference between Search Bar vs. Search Bar & Search Display Controller?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Search Bar + Search Display Controller includes other bits of functionality like loading a results table view, showing the "no results" view if nothing is set, etc.

Comment: I think you should provide some more information or link with "etc"