# Differences between search bar and search display controller

Tags: cocoa-touch, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

What is the difference between a search bar and a search display controller? When should I use one or the other?

Comment: Please give some specifics of your situation, some criteria to make this more concrete.

Comment: I'd like to implement a search in a table view controller. I'm wondering what is the difference between those 2 controls.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3379613/what-is-the-difference-between-search-bar-vs-search-bar-search-display-contro

Check out the link above